# How to grab an existing object and update one of its properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am learning javascript and just having an issue understanding on how to grab an existing object and update a property within that object.

I have an ICreatedAddress object and I am simply saying populate it with some details. Then what I want to do is if I ever need to grab a token from localStorage, I will update the 'token' property in IUIAddress to ensure it contains that localStorage token. My issue is I do not know how to grab the ICreatedAddress object that's been populated and update that token property.

Below is the code where I set up the ICreatedAddress object and populate it.

```
export interface IUiAddress {
  address: ICreatedAddress;
  addressConfig: IAddressConfig;
}

export interface IAddressConfig {
  deviceId: string;
}

....

export async function createAddress(addressConfig: IAddressConfig) {
  let address: ICreatedAddress = {
    addressLine: addressConfig.addressLine,
    city: addressConfig.city,
    ...(addressConfig.country !== 'UK' && {
      token: `Bearer ${
        (await authDevice(addressConfig.deviceId, '100.100.150.150')).body.authDevice
      }`,
    }),
  };
  return <IUiAddress>{ address: address, addressConfig: addressConfig };
}
```

Below is the method which simply handles getting the token from localStorage and updating the token property. The error I am receiving is stating a declaration or statement expected.

```
export function setAuthTokenFromLocalStorage(address: ICreatedAddress) {
  ...(address && {
    token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
  };
```

}

Comment: in `setAuthTokenFromLocalStorage`  function you are just returning single token you just need to do is { address && { ...address, token:localStorage.getItem('token') }

Comment: Ah thank you, still learning the syntax and I was close but just couldn't figure it out. Thanks Mohit